# Long wait to get Hotspot feature going on Verizon iPhone 4S

Tags: iphone, tethering, cellular-carriers

How long does it take between calling Verizon to set up the Hotspot feature until you are actually able to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for me was discovered after calling VZW for the third time and having my case  escalated to Tier Two. It was to go to Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset Network Settings. Then it power cycled and afterwards I was able to use the feature. Thanks @MrDaniel for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Just did this the other day and it took less than 30 mins, its probably ready instantly after you add it to you account, but in practice it takes longer because it did not just start working automatically on  the phone, the phone needed to call Verizon to get updates to what it could do first. I only needed to call them so that they could tell me to do steps 1 and 2 below. Knowing that you don't even really need to call them.

The next thing you do after adding the Mobile broadband features to your account is:

1. Reboot the iPhone
2. Dial <kbd>*</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>8</kbd> and then select option <kbd>2</kbd> (the one for updating phone's mobile or roaming features)
3. Then you are good to go and set up the hotspot via USB, Wifi or Bluetooth.

Note: if that fails then they say:

> ... please call us from a different device at (800) 922-0204

Comment: It's not working for me. Still says I have to call to have it added to my account, even after an hour and a half.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what Mine was doing too until I did the above rebooting of the iPhone and updating the mobile abilities as noted above. If you try the Above and it still does not work I would call Verizon

Comment: alord1689, Where you able to add the $20 add-on to your account for 2GB Mobile Hotspot?

Comment: I did it on the phone. When I try to access my features on the website it says that information is unavailable at this time.

Comment: They said it's Option 1, not 2. Option 2 is for when you're not on VZW towers.

Comment: Ya it looks like unfortunately something else may have gone wrong on Verizon's end, so you may need to call then to sort out all the account details.

Comment: Still didn't work.